# Subgroups of order $12$ of $PSL(2,11)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

How can I prove that the group $PSL(2,11)$ has a subgroup of order $12$ isomorphic to $A_4$ and another subgroup of order $12$ isomorphic to the dihedral $D_{12}$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Section II.8 of Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I describes the subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2, q)$, for $q$ a prime-power.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry - my mistake!