# $PSL(2, 11)$ has non isomorphic Hall subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was reading Robinson's book "A Course in the Theory of Groups". In section 9.1 (Hall $\pi$-subgroups) it is commented that, in an insoluble group, the Hall $\pi$-subgroups may not be conjugate. As an example, the author says that the simple group $PSL(2, 11)$ has subgroups isomorphic with $D_{12}$ and $A_{4}$, which are non isomorphic Hall {2, 3}-subgroups and therefore not conjugates.

I would like to know why $PSL(2, 11)$ has subgroups isomorphic with $D_{12}$ and $A_{4}$.

I never heard before of the subgroup $PSL$, so I tried reading about it a bit. I found the following link: [Subgroups of order $12$ of $PSL(2,11)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666914/subgroups-of-order-12-of-psl2-11), which points to "Section II.8 of Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I" book. Unfortunately, I don't know German, so it did not help me.

EDIT: by following the link suggested as an answer ([Reference for the subgroup structure of $PSL(2,q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/reference-for-the-subgroup-structure-of-psl2-q)), I found Suzuki's Group Theory(I) book. In the section 3.6 the author find all the subgroups of $PSL(2, q)$. Problem solved, thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What $PSL$ is? Or why does $PSL(2,11)$ have those specific subgroups?

Comment: I am sorry, my question was why $PSL(2, 11)$ has this specific subgroups. I will change my question to make it clearer.